# How do I activate a script only if the mouse is at a certain coordinate of the screen without interfering with my keyboard?

Tags: autohotkey

I cooked up a script that lets me map my keyboard's media shortcuts to my mouse LRM buttons when they are pressed while the mouse coordinate is leftmost or rightmost of the screen. While it does work, I'm having having strange side effects:

- When I have caps lock on, ever few strokes the letter comes out lowercase.
- When I use shift to type capital letters for an extended period of time, this will turn on caps lock

Using the keyboard history, I see that my script is constantly sending the "Alt Up" key, I did this so that it release the "Alt Down" state, but something is off.

My goal is to send an modifier key when a mouse is over a certain coordinate, so that when I click with that mouse button, it launches another ahk-programmed shortcut. But can't figure out where the logic error is in my code or thinking process.

Here's the script:

```
; ------------------------
; Global Initializers
#InstallKeybdHook
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 1

; ---------------------
; Control Spotify; position your mouse top-most edge and use L/M/R-mouse keys.

SetTimer, WatchCursorx, 1000
return

WatchCursorx:
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos

;Based on location of the mouse simulate shortcut activation

If (xpos == 2559 || xpos == 0)
{
    Send {Alt Down}
}
Else
{
    Send {Alt Up}
}
return

;Define shortcuts mentioned above

!RButton::
Send {Media_Next}
return

!LButton::
Send {Media_Prev}
return

!MButton::
send {Media_Play_Pause}
return
```

Comment: One thing is that every 1 second (based on `SetTimer`) you check mouse position and if not on an edge, send the `Alt Up` so that's why you get that so frequently, and that is probably interfering in other ways . . .

Comment: Therefore, just flip the logic.  Make some ordinary `L M R` click commands that first look to see where the mouse is, and if at edge of screen when pressed, sends those media keys, and else, send the unmodified `L M R` clicks.  No `SetTimer` needed. In the meantime, you can also keep your `Alt + L M R` clicks as you had them for when you are actually pressing the `Alt` key and click a mouse button while not at an edge . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#If`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm)</sup> is meant for this.
You could use it for example like this:

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

#If, MouseOnTheRight()
LButton::SendInput, {Media_Prev}
RButton::SendInput, {Media_Next}
MButton::SendInput, {Media_Play_Pause}
#If

MouseOnTheRight()
{
    MouseGetPos, x
    return x == A_ScreenWidth - 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Two questions:
1. Why do you need the second #If; in the docs they don't show an example with two of them.
2. Is there a way to short-hand my function:
[MouseOnEdge()
{
    MouseGetPos, x
 if (x == 0 || x = 2559){
  return True
 }
}]

or add code to your MouseOnTheRight function to include a check for the left-most alternative, like my function does?

Comment: 3. How come your #If structure continuously executes, even though there is no timer and watcher? In PGlim's note, they places the code inside the hot key itself, so that made sense. Curious.

Comment: The second empty `#If` resets the context sensitivity of hotkeys. It's also described in the docs. Technically it's not needed here, since don't have any other other hotkeys in the script. But in any case it's good practice to remember to also end your context sensitive blocks. And yes, your if statement can be compacted into this: `return x == 0 || x == A_ScreenWidth - 1`, or even shorter, like this `return !x || x == A_ScreenWidth - 1`.

Comment: And this works because of how context sensitive hotkeys work in AHK. After you press the button, AHK runs the related code (in this case the related code is running the function and determining whether the function returned `true` or not) to determine whether or not the hotkey should activate. You can also do this inside the hotkey block, like in the other answer, but in that case you lose the native functionality of the key. Which is no good of course, that's why you can create context sensitive hotkeys with AHK.

Comment: No, no "loss of native functionality" of key in the "other answer" as the `~` in front of the hotkey means to pass through the original key (in this case, a mouse click).  In fact, that is why the right click triggers the context menu even on the edges (as explained).  So while the media keys do fire, so do the original mouse clicks.  So no problem clicking, dragging, etc. outside the edges, it all work . . .

Comment: You're right, I said it the wrong way around. Since the tilde prefix is used, the issue is not getting rid of the native functionality when needed.

Comment: @0x464e, I'm confused by the notation 'return !x || x == some other value.' I read that as return if not x or x == some value. But in my function I'm specifically say 0 or the other value. Can you explain?

Comment: `0` evaluates to `false` (or more accurately, `false` is `0`, there is no bool data type in AHK, the built-in variables `true` and `false` contain `1` and `0`), so that's why you can do `!x`. You're basically checking "is x false?", and that check will return true if x is `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comments, try it like this:

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

~RButton::
    MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
    If (xpos == 2559 || xpos == 0)
    {
        Send {Media_Next}
        sleep, 500
        Send {esc} ' this gets rid of right context menu
    }
return

~LButton::
    MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
    If (xpos == 2559 || xpos == 0)
        Send {Media_Prev}
return

~MButton::
    MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
    If (xpos == 2559 || xpos == 0)
        Send {Media_Play_Pause}
return
```

Note, the preceding `~` lets the original mouse click go through so ordinarily the context menu will come up on right click. I add a `Sleep` and `Send Escape` key to dismiss . . . Ymmv

Comment: Thank you for your notes and solution PGilm; I totally did not think of the reverse notion!